# Add search box to newsletter page on Stack Exchange main site

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, stackexchange.com, newsletter

On the Stack Exchange [newsletter subscription page](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters), there are short lists of the sites in categories.  If I'm looking for a site that isn't there I have to start clicking on the 'show more X xxxxxx sites` link for every category until I find what I'm looking for.

How about putting a search box on that page so we can bring up the site we're looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been implemented.

The [Stack Exchange newsletters page](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) has a little search box at the top now.